# Covering/Blocking Gap Between Wood Wall And Foundation Block in Garage

Tags: garage, cinderblock

I have a 24'x30' garage with an on-grade block foundation that I plan on finishing to use as an office/workshop of sorts.  Before I start putting in insulation and drywall, I want to attempt to seal up any gaps, but as a DIYer I don't know what to do about these gaps between my framing and the foundation inside.  This is a new build and I already have ants starting to invade.  I am already in the process of spraying pesticides/diatomaceous earth as well. Do I need to fill these blocks with concrete or am I overthinking the requirements here?  Are there any other options out there?

[image: Wall above 6" block]
[image: Close up]

Comment: They sure didn't spend $10 on sill seal, did they? Shoddy job.

Comment: It appears they did not.  Just plopped it down right on top with nothing in-between.

Comment: Is the bottom plate at least PT?

Comment: I don't think it is PT but it is HT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they were going to be filled with concrete, it should have been done before the wall was placed.

The evidently untreated (color does not look like treated lumber in this photograph, to me) bottom plate in direct contact with concrete blocks will rot out due to moisture wicking up the concrete block, in time. A cheap roll of sill seal would have broken that wood/concrete contact, and sealed gaps.

So, overall, it's a poor job thus far.

Probably filling the block cores with foam and cutting off the excess is about as well as you can do without jacking up the building to correct the mistakes. It's likely enough foam to justify a larger tank package (or hiring a sprayfoam contractor) rather than doing it with little cans.

Comment: Yikes, I was afraid this would be the answer.  I was trying to calculate how many cans I'd need yesterday for spray foam which led me to hoping there was another way.  I should have done more research and asked questions before this job was done. Looks like I'll be shelling out even more money here now.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: Perhaps first attempt to apply whatever you can get these days for "paint-on wood preservative"  to the bottom plate. Unless you'll be jacking the building up for a better fix...

Comment: I've got some Nisus PenaShield that I'll spray on this weekend.  Jacking it isn't going to be an option unless the contractor will pony up for it.  I can't see that happening.